# Numerical Integration of System of Second-Order Differential Equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

Can Mathematica numerically integrate (and make an x-y plot of the solution of) a system of two second-order ODEs $$\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}=A(t, x(t), y(t), \frac{dx(t)}{dt}, \frac{dy(t)}{dt})$$ $$\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2}=B(t, x(t), y(t), \frac{dx(t)}{dt}, \frac{dy(t)}{dt})$$

like this? I remember trying NDSolve without it working.

Comment: NDSolve is very good so it should be able to do it if you give it the actual specification of $A,B$ and all initial/boundary conditions. It helps to see what you tried.

Comment: Okay, I'll try again. If it doesn't work, can I type the error message here?

Comment: You can show in plain text the code you used and you can also show the error message. You do not have to type the error message. Jus either copy it or make screen shot of it.

Comment: Depends on the form of $A$ and $B$.  For example if these functions have singularities like a $\frac{1}{x'}$ term then integrating close to $x'(t)=0$ will encounter a singularity and fail.  Suggest you start with a very simple linear form of $A$ and $B$ and just practice with initial conditions and plotting the results.  If you have Mathematica, just type `NDSolve` in a notebook.   Hover over it, press the "I" and study and work the examples.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
sol[t_] = 
 NDSolveValue[
    {x'[t] == v[t], 
     v'[t] == Sin[5 t] y[t] + Cos[3 t] w[t] - 9 x[t],
     y'[t] == w[t], w'[t] == ArcTan[t] x[t] + Erf[t] v[t] - 7 y[t],
     x[0] == 0, v[0] == 1, y[0] == -5, w[0] == 0}, 
    {x[t], v[t], y[t],w[t]}, 
     {t, 0, 27}]

  ParametricPlot[{sol[t][[1]], sol[t][[3]]} , {t, 0, 27},
 PlotLabel -> "{x[t],y[t]}", ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &)]
```

[image: 2. order ODE system]

Comment: Okay, this is mostly pretty clear, but I have some questions about certain parts of the code: what is the purpose of the underscore after the $t$ at the top, and what do the values of $1$ and $3$ in ParametricPlot represent?

Comment: The underscrore t_ is short for Pattern[t]. in the sequence of variables It denotes the symbol in the expression, that plot feed its numerical time values. Plot is non-AI, it is a simple numerical graphics engine number-in -> point-out. The function sol[t] produces a vector with the two pairs of position and velocity values. sol[t] [[ n ]] picks part n.